# Calling local variable in remote host

Tags: shell

below script is not working in remote host

```
PARAMETER="123  456"
ssh user@host PARAMETER="$PARAMETER" bash -s <<- __EOF
    echo \$PARAMETER
__EOF
```

but when I try Below it is working fine

```
PARAMETER="123"
ssh user@host PARAMETER="$PARAMETER" bash -s <<- __EOF
    echo \$PARAMETER
__EOF
```

Looks like it is not accepting space in the variable. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

As locally, you have to quote variable expansion to disable word splitting. `echo "$var"` not `echo $var`.

And you have to quote the value for unquoting by ssh:

```
ssh user@host PARAMETER="$(printf "%q" "$PARAMETER")" bash -s <<- __EOF
    echo "\$PARAMETER"
__EOF
```

If you are using stdin, I suggest to use to transfer all context with stdin without caring of super-double-quoting:

```
# define function with the code you want to run, normally quoted
work() {
   echo "$PARAMETER"
}
ssh user@host bash -s <<EOF
$(declare -p PARAMETER)  # serialize variables
$(declare -f work)       # serialize functions
work                     # run the function
EOF
```

Comment: $cat 2.sh
 #!/bin/bash
PARTITION=$1
if [ ! "$PARTITION" ];then
 echo "Please pass mandatory arguments ::: -partition <HOURLY/DAILY/MONTHLY>"
 exit
fi
if [ "$PARTITION" = HOURLY ]
then
name1=$(cat /home/pdsops/new_scripts/11.txt| grep -i hourly|cut -d'|' -f 1)
echo $name1
 usr@host  <<- __EOF "for i in \\$name1; do echo \$i; done"
__EOF
                fi

Comment: $ cat 11.txt
/user/datasystems/snapshots/le_indexer_v2/|hourly|
/user/datasystems/snapshots/ae_indexer_v2/|hourly|
/user/datasystems/snapshots/ae_indexer_full_today_v2/|daily|
/user/datasystems/snapshots/appear_attr_indexer_full_today_v2/|daily|
 it is throwing below error
$ sh 2.sh HOURLY
/user/datasystems/snapshots/le_indexer_v2/ /user/datasystems/snapshots/ae_indexer_v2/
 syntax error near unexpected token `/user/datasystems/snapshots/ae_indexer_v2/'
`/user/datasystems/snapshots/ae_indexer_v2/; do echo $i; done'

Comment: Above is my script but throwing error as can be seen. Please suggest